# Bring the web browser windows to front when new notification arrives

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a browser-based application that needs to be able to get users' attention when the user receives an incoming notification even if the user has minimized the browser.

Searching I was not able to find a solution, except showing a popup which I can handle to bring to front and focus.

It needs to be cross-browser (IE, Edge, Chrome, Safari at least).

My application is using AspNetZero framework version 6.0. I am receiving notifications by Signal-R and Oracle Notifications. So, when a new record is added in a table, it calls a javascript event in the web browser. This event is creating a Modal Dialog using the framework and playing an audio file. It is not creating a new windows popup, at this moment, it is out of context.

It would be nice if I could blink the taskbar icon, bring the web browser to front, and play the sound. Any suggestions on how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript Notification API (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/notification) to show a desktop notification to the user.